# Как кастомизировать DatePicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

Вопрос: Как в DatePicker сделать так чтобы при открытии календаря:

1. Выходные и праздничные дни отмечались красным цветом
2. Сделать некликабельным праздники, выходные и прошедшие дни
3. Как пометить прошедшие дни серым цветом

Comment: Если имеется в виду `System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker`, то это оболочка над нативным компонентом WinAPI. Кастомизировать его почти невозможно. Лучше поищите подходящий контрол в какой-нибудь библиотеке. Или встройте пикер из WPF.